# http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ выводит что то не то

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Когда всё нормально то выводится обычная html страница phpmyadmin а у меня выводится этот текст

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use PhpMyAdmin\Common;
use PhpMyAdmin\Routing;

if (! defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
    // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
    define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    // phpcs:enable
}

if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70205) {
    die('<p>PHP 7.2.5+ is required.</p><p>Currently installed version is: ' . PHP_VERSION . '</p>');
}

// phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
define('PHPMYADMIN', true);
// phpcs:enable

require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/constants.php';

/**
 * Activate autoloader
 */
if (! @is_readable(AUTOLOAD_FILE)) {
    die(
        '<p>File <samp>' . AUTOLOAD_FILE . '</samp> missing or not readable.</p>'
        . '<p>Most likely you did not run Composer to '
        . '<a href="https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#installing-from-git">'
        . 'install library files</a>.</p>'
    );
}

require AUTOLOAD_FILE;

global $route, $containerBuilder, $request;

Common::run();

$dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher();
Routing::callControllerForRoute($request, $route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);
```

я это сделал в код так как оно без этого не вставлялось.
устанавливал по схеме с этого сайта https://hackware.ru/?p=15409.

Comment: У вас php не работает похоже) сервер отдает статику) код давать не нужно, так как pma готовый релиз (продакшн), там не нужно что-то делать в файлах, если что-то не работает, значит проблема у вас, а не в скрипте) и не важно кали у вас или арч...

Comment: @Jour блин а что делать удалять и все переустанавливать ? Или всё-таки что то можно изменить?